# restoring a modal view controller

Tags: state-restoration

```
<p>Modal view controller's delegate is (null) with attempting to restore it </p>
```

The method is not being called... 
+ (UIViewController *)viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:(NSArray *)identifierComponents
 after defining a restorationClass

AppDelegate.m is not using

```
 -(UIViewController *)application:(UIApplication *)application viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:(NSArray *)identifierComponents coder:(NSCoder *)coder
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, try to encode your delegate and decode it when restoring a view controller. Restoring only your view controller won't help. You have to restore all data and delegates to be able to function the app properly.